# Match Duplicates within Time Range

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

Trying to count duplicate values coming in 2 minute intervals in `Columns A & B`. I can get the count of the number of occurrences w/ `=COUNTIFS(E:E,">="&A2,E:E,"<="&A3)` but having issues matching if those values are duplicate. Raw data is in `Columns D & E`.

| Time 2m Intervals | Match Count |  | Data In | Time In |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8:30:00 AM | 2 |  | Apple123 | 8:30:00 AM |
| 8:32:00 AM | 2 |  | Apple456 | 8:30:00 AM |
| 8:34:00 AM | 5 |  | Apple789 | 8:30:00 AM |
| 8:36:00 AM | 2 |  | Apple123 | 8:31:00 AM |
| 8:38:00 AM | 2 |  | Orange123 | 8:32:00 AM |
| 8:40:00 AM | N/A |  | Apple789 | 8:33:00 AM |
|  |  |  | Apple789 | 8:34:00 AM |
|  |  |  | Orange456 | 8:34:00 AM |
|  |  |  | Orange456 | 8:35:00 AM |
|  |  |  | Orange456 | 8:35:00 AM |
|  |  |  | Orange123 | 8:36:00 AM |
|  |  |  | Orange123 | 8:36:00 AM |
|  |  |  | Apple789 | 8:37:00 AM |
|  |  |  | Apple123 | 8:38:00 AM |
|  |  |  | Apple123 | 8:39:00 AM |
|  |  |  | Orange789 | 8:40:00 AM |

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for formulas or VBA code?

Comment: Formula if possible.

Comment: Please remove `vba` tag if you're looking for formulas solution.  btw, [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Thanks for info I fixed the ? I forgot about the image issues imbedded inside ?s.

Comment: What's the expected result on B2? What's the logic?

Comment: The image shows colors that match the intended result for B2 and so on. For example in B2 the result is 2 because within the time range of 8:30 to 8:32 there are 2 matches. Apple123. B4 has 5 matches because between 8:34 and 8:36 there are 5 matches Orange123 and Orange456.

Comment: Just trying to count duplicates within a time range of 2minutes. I guess B2 could also say 1 match and B4 could say 2 matches also. Instead of summing the actual amount of matches.

Comment: So may I know for `B5` why does it show `0` even when it has `2` duplicates, if its a typo then you could try this : `=LET(x, FILTER($D$2:$D$17,($E$2:$E$17>=A2)*($E$2:$E$17<=TIME(,2,)+A2)), ROWS(x)-ROWS(UNIQUE(x,,1)))` Also your markdown data is showing wrong output for cell `B2` instead of `2` it shows `5`

Comment: Thanks. I am using an older version of excel. Is there a way to do it w/out Filter? I corrected the markdown data.   Yes, that is a typo B5 should read 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, then one could use the following formula and this assumes, there is no excel constraints as per the tags posted.

[image]

---

```
=LET(x, FILTER(D:D,(E:E>=A2)*(E:E<=TIME(,2,)+A2)), ROWS(x)-ROWS(UNIQUE(x,,1)))
```

---

Or, one single dynamic array formula using either `MAP()` or `BYROW()`

```
=MAP(A2:A7,LAMBDA(y, LET(x, FILTER(D:D,(E:E>=y)*(E:E<=TIME(,2,)+y)), ROWS(x)-ROWS(UNIQUE(x,,1)))))
```

---

*Also it is highly suggested and recommended to use `Structured References` aka `Tables` (**for the source data since dynamic array formulas dont work with tables but the feature mentioned helps in formulas when used with source data**) in Excel which makes it easier to read, understand formula, as well as  it automatically adjust rows or columns when added or removed from the tables. So using `Tables` reference the formula will be,*

[image]

---

```
=LET(x, FILTER(Timetbl[Data In],(Timetbl[Time In]>=A2)*(Timetbl[Time In]<=TIME(,2,)+A2)), ROWS(x)-ROWS(UNIQUE(x,,1)))
```

---

Or,

```
=BYROW(A2:A7,LAMBDA(y, LET(x, 
 FILTER(Timetbl[Data In],(Timetbl[Time In]>=y)*
 (Timetbl[Time In]<=TIME(,2,)+y)), ROWS(x)-ROWS(UNIQUE(x,,1)))))
```

---

For Excel 2019:

[image]

---

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Timetbl[Time In]>=A2)*(Timetbl[Time In]<=A2+TIME(,2,)))-
 SUMPRODUCT(N(IFERROR(IF((Timetbl[Time In]>=A2)*(Timetbl[Time In]<=A2+TIME(,2,)),
 FREQUENCY(MATCH(Timetbl[Data In]&"|"&(Timetbl[Time In]>=A2)*(Timetbl[Time In]<=A2+TIME(,2,)),
 Timetbl[Data In]&"|"&(Timetbl[Time In]>=A2)*(Timetbl[Time In]<=A2+TIME(,2,)),0),ROW(Timetbl[Data In])-ROW($D$2)+1)=1,0),0)))
```

---

Comment: Is there a way to do it w/ out filter? My excel 2019 doesn’t support Filter yet.

Comment: @mjac but `Excel 2019` does supports `FILTER()` function, alright let me try another approach.

Comment: @mjac updated the answers, for `Excel 2019` it will be quite large!

Comment: Working on doing it w/out using a table. Its close but still needs work. `=SUMPRODUCT(((E:E)>=A3)*((E:E)<=A3+TIME(,2,)))- SUMPRODUCT(N(IFERROR(IF(((E:E)>=A3)*((E:E)<=A3+TIME(,2,)), FREQUENCY(MATCH((D:D)&"|"&((E:E)>=A3)*((E:E)<=A3+TIME(,2,)), (D:D)&"|"&((E:E)>=A3)*((E:E)<=A3+TIME(,2,)),0),ROW((D:D))-ROW($D$2)+1)=1,0),0)))`

Comment: @mjac if you use formula without absolute references then you will certainly get an error pop `Excel has ran out of resources` instead use the structured references. Also may i ask what it needs to works please explain

Comment: I got it too work per your comment. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @mjac glad to know it worked for you thank you very much !

Comment: Any help w/ this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77867145/duplicate-qty-match-within-time-range

Comment: The output for `08:34:00 AM` should be `34571`

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to count everything twice at the boundaries of time intervals? You use inequalities `>=` and `<=`. In my opinion, one of the inequalities should be strict.
My proposal for older versions of Excel with an auxiliary column with unicates.
[image: Duplicates_time]

Formula used for unicates in M2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(T(+$D$2:$D$21),MATCH(0,COUNTIF(M$1:M1,$D$2:$D$21),0)),"")
```

Formula used for counting duplicates with `>=` and `<=` in O2:

```
=SUM(IFERROR((COUNTIFS($E:$E,">="&$N2,$E:$E,"<="&$N3,$D:$D,$M$2:$M$21)-2)^0.5^2+2,0))
```

And similar formula with `>=` and `<` in P2:

```
=SUM(IFERROR((COUNTIFS($E:$E,">="&$N2,$E:$E,"<"&$N3,$D:$D,$M$2:$M$21)-2)^0.5^2+2,0))
```

The ends of the formulas may look a bit strange, but I wanted to avoid counting the `COUNTIFS` twice.
Formulas require `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` in older versions of Excel.