# Duplicate & Qty Match within Time Range

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

Formula counts duplicate values coming in 2-minute intervals in `Columns A & B`. Having issues summing the Qtys in `Column C` relating to the counted matches. Raw data is in `Columns D, E & F`. Goal is to add to this formula or create a new `Column C` to sum up the Qtys in `Column F` relating to the matched counts.

Formula in `Column B`:

`{=SUMPRODUCT((($E$2:$E$50000)>=A2)*(($E$2:$E$50000)<=A2+TIME(,2,)))- SUMPRODUCT(N(IFERROR(IF((($E$2:$E$50000)>=A2)*(($E$2:$E$50000)<=A2+TIME(,2,)), FREQUENCY(MATCH(($D$2:$D$50000)&"|"&(($E$2:$E$50000)>=A2)*(($E$2:$E$50000)<=A2+TIME(,2,)), ($D$2:$D$50000)&"|"&(($E$2:$E$50000)>=A2)*(($E$2:$E$50000)<=A2+TIME(,2,)),0),ROW(($D$2:$D$50000))-ROW($D$2)+1)=1,0),0)))}`

[image]

| Time 2m Intervals | Match Count | Qty Sum | Data In | Time In | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8:30:00 AM | 2 | 456 | Apple123 | 8:30:00 AM | 1 |
| 8:32:00 AM | 2 | 116 | Apple456 | 8:30:00 AM | 2 |
| 8:34:00 AM | 5 | 34,571 | Apple789 | 8:30:00 AM | 300 |
| 8:36:00 AM | 2 | 33,666 | Apple123 | 8:31:00 AM | 455 |
| 8:38:00 AM | 2 | 79 | Orange123 | 8:32:00 AM | 6 |
| 8:40:00 AM | 0 | 0 | Apple789 | 8:33:00 AM | 31 |
|  |  |  | Apple789 | 8:34:00 AM | 85 |
|  |  |  | Orange456 | 8:34:00 AM | 321 |
|  |  |  | Orange456 | 8:35:00 AM | 3 |
|  |  |  | Orange456 | 8:35:00 AM | 581 |
|  |  |  | Orange123 | 8:36:00 AM | 333 |
|  |  |  | Orange123 | 8:36:00 AM | 33,333 |
|  |  |  | Apple789 | 8:37:00 AM | 4 |
|  |  |  | Apple123 | 8:38:00 AM | 23 |
|  |  |  | Apple123 | 8:39:00 AM | 56 |
|  |  |  | Orange789 | 8:40:00 AM | 9 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula remains same like the old one, only we need to use another multiplication of the `QTY` array/range.

[image]

---

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Timetbl[Time In]>=A2)*(Timetbl[Time In]<=A2+TIME(,2,))*Timetbl[Qty])-
 SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(N(IFERROR(IF((Timetbl[Time In]>=A2)*(Timetbl[Time In]<=A2+TIME(,2,)),
 FREQUENCY(MATCH(Timetbl[Data In]&"|"&(Timetbl[Time In]>=A2)*(Timetbl[Time In]<=A2+TIME(,2,)),
 Timetbl[Data In]&"|"&(Timetbl[Time In]>=A2)*(Timetbl[Time In]<=A2+TIME(,2,)),0),ROW(Timetbl[Data In])-ROW($E$2)+1)=1,0),0))*Timetbl[Qty],0))
```

---

Comment: Were close I think I have a `( )` off somewhere. I am getting `N/A` `=SUMPRODUCT(($E$2:$E$50000)>=A2)*($E$2:$E$50000)<=A2+TIME(,2,)*($F$2:$F$50000)-SUMPRODUCT(N(IFERROR(IF((($E$2:$E$50000)>=A2)*(($E$2:$E$50000)<=A2+TIME(,2,)),FREQUENCY(MATCH(($D$2:$D$50000)&"|"&(($E$2:$E$50000)>=A2)*(($E$2:$E$50000)<=A2+TIME(,2,)),($D$2:$D$50000)&"|"&(($E$2:$E$50000)>=A2)*(($E$2:$E$50000)<=A2+TIME(,2,)),0),ROW(($D$2:$D$50000))-ROW($D$2)+1)=1,0),0))*($F$2:$F$50000))`

Comment: @mjac let me enter the same in my worksheet

Comment: @mjac here you go, enter this formula: `=SUMPRODUCT(($E$2:$E$50000>=A2)*($E$2:$E$50000<=A2+TIME(,2,))*$F$2:$F$50000)-
 SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(N(IFERROR(IF(($E$2:$E$50000>=A2)*($E$2:$E$50000<=A2+TIME(,2,)),
 FREQUENCY(MATCH($D$2:$D$50000&"|"&($E$2:$E$50000>=A2)*($E$2:$E$50000<=A2+TIME(,2,)),
 $D$2:$D$50000&"|"&($E$2:$E$50000>=A2)*($E$2:$E$50000<=A2+TIME(,2,)),0),ROW($D$2:$D$50000)-ROW($D$2)+1)=1,0),0))*$F$2:$F$50000,0))`